# Isolated Docker environments via SSH

Tags: docker

I am setting up a series of Linux command line challenges (for internal use/training), similar to those at OverTheWire.org's Bandit. From some reading I have done of their infrastructure, they setup things as such:

> All ssh-based games on OverTheWire run in Docker containers. When you
>   login with SSH to one of the games, a fresh Docker container is
>   created just for you. Noone else is logged in into your container, nor
>   are there any files from other players lying around. We opted for this
>   setup to provide each player with a clean environment to experiment
>   and learn in, which is automatically cleaned up when you log out.

This seems like an ideal solution, since everyone who logs in gets a completely clean environment (destroyed on logout) so that simultaneous players do not interfere with each other.

I am very new to Docker and understand it in principle, but am unsure about how to setup a similar system - particularly spawn new Docker instances on SSH login to a server and then destroy the instance on logout/disconnection.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to design/implement this kind of setup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there are two main goals here. First undestand what docker really makes and how it works. Second the sistem that orquestates the whole sistem.

Let me make some brief and short introduction. I won't go into details but mainly docker is a plaform that works like a system virtualization that lets you isolate a process, operating system or a whole aplication without any kind of hypervisor. The container shares the kernel of the host system and all that it cointains is islated from the host and the rest of the containers.

So the basic principle you are looking for is a system that orchestrates containers that has an ssh server with the port 22 open. Although there are many ways of how you could reach this goal, one way it can be with this [docker sshd server image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd/).

```
docker run -itd --rm rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd bash
```

- Docker needs a process to keep alive. By using **-it** you are creating an interactive session with the "bash" interpreter. This will keep alive the container plus lets you start a bash terminal inside an isolated virtual ubuntu server.
- **--rm**: will remove the container once you exists from the container.
- **rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd**: it is the docker image id.

As you can see, there is a lack of a system that connects between your aplication and this docker platform. One approach would it be with [a library](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that python has that uses the docker client programaticaly. As an advice I would recomend you to install docker in your computer and to try to create a couple of ubuntu servers with ssh server and to connect into it from your host. It will help you to see if it's really necesary to have sshd server, the network requisites you will need if so, to traffic all the clients into the containers. Read the oficial [docker network documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/).

With the example I had described a new fresh terminal is started and there is no need to connect to the docker via ssh. By using this way you won't need to route the traffic, indentify the host free ports to connect your host to the containers or to check and shutdown the container once the connection has finished. Otherwhise the container will keep alive.

There are many ways where your system can be made and I would strongly recomend to you to start by creating some containers with the docker tool and start to understand how it works.